# PagedList RecyclerView jumping after pagedList invalidation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack, android-paging, epoxy

### Setup :

We are using `PagedListEpoxyController`, `RxPagedListBuilder`, `ItemKeyedDataSource` with a runtime `Mockgenerator` which just creates a user with respect to the index of data that is generated, for eg. **user1, user100, user500** etc.

#### Paging configuration is :

```
val pageSize = 50
val initialLoadSizeHint = 80
val prefetchDistance = 16
```

### Expected behaviour

Whenever we **scroll down to** the **400th** item and **come back** to the **300th** item and **invalidate** the list by clicking **Follow/Unfollow** the UI jumps. When the button is clicked the PagedList is invalidated like this:

[image]

`followers.dataSource.invalidate()`

`loadInitial()` inside `ItemKeyedDataSource` should be called with the value of `params.key` so we can get the same page that was previously displayed to be re-displayed. For example if **user300** was **visible** in the screen, that item `requestedInitialKey` should be in the **range of [user221,user280]**.

## Where is the issue?

Paging Library tracks of the `last item that was fetched in the pagedList` before invalidation `but does not` provide a way to know which was the `last item/range that was visible` in the screen just before invalidation.

After invalidating the pagedList, The first callback which gets called after pagedList invalidation is `loadInitial(params : LoadInitialParams, callback : LoadInitialCallback)` with the `params` only holds the information about pageSize and placeholder along with `requestedInitialKey` as `last item that was fetched` before invalidation which is very misleading. Why, `after invalidation` a pagedList does `request` the last item to be fetched in the list as the `requestedInitialKey / item in the firstPage` rather than `the last item that was displayed before invalidation`?. Sorry if I have totally misunderstood this thing but couldn't really make sense of it.

### Question :

I wish `pagedList` to **start fetching the first page** in new PagedList after invalidation from the **previous scroll Location** rather than the **last item in the previous pagedList**.

- But if PagedList is not supposed to work this way then **How can I know any of the item/index that was previously visible** in the screen before invalidation?
- If I can't do that currently either, what is the **recommended way to achieve this requirement**?

This issue can be found here :

To reproduce : Scroll down far enough (like 60th item) and press **"Refresh"** you will see the jump in the list. 
[Link to github issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/pull/591)

Comment: Any updates? Have the same problem on my project.

Answer (score 0):

The way we solved this issue is, UI only listens from Room Database as a single source of truth. This issue is not present in that setup. But when we use ItemKeyedDatasource, this issue is persistent even until now.

Comment: What about PageKeyedDataSource where the endpoint accepts filter parameters? How do you cache it in this instance?